# Stepper motor with ESP32 not moving, used to intermittently move but not as intended, tips on troubleshooting this setup?

Tags: stepper-motor, esp32

[image]

ABREF was set to 3v3, but it can be lowered.

Datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8825.pdf#page=18

[image]

Arduino, minimal code:

```c
/*
 * ESP32
 * https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Espressif-Systems/ESP32-DevKitC-32D
 */

//const int dirPinX = 0;  // old
const int dirPinX = 4;
const int stepPinX = 2;

const int dirPinY = 19;
const int stepPinY = 18;

const int mode0Pin = 21;
const int mode1Pin = 23;
const int  DAC_CH2 = 26;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(stepPinX, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPinX, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(mode0Pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(mode1Pin, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(mode0Pin, LOW); // microstepping 1/2 if high and Pin1 is low
  digitalWrite(mode1Pin, LOW); // 1/8 if both high

  dacWrite(DAC_CH2, 255);      // Full power
  //dacWrite(DAC_CH2, 0); 
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(dirPinX, HIGH);
  for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    stepX();
  // Move back
  digitalWrite(dirPinX, LOW);
  for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    stepX();
}

void stepX()
{
  digitalWrite(stepPinX, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(500);
  digitalWrite(stepPinX, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(500);
}
```

I tried assembling more PCBs. Same issue. I checked all voltages with a DMM, and they all seem to be as expected. See anything that should be changed? Any tips on troubleshooting from here?

Comment: Does it work with longer delays?

Comment: It sounds like it is taking very small steps from when the LOW delay is set from values 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, etc. But still no real movement that I can see.

Comment: I had a similar issue because I accidentially swapped motor wires. Do you have a datasheet of the motor? The recommended start frequency is relevant.

Comment: It works on the old version of the PCB. It's just that version doesn't have a schematic tied to it (it's just a copy/paste footprint).